# How to release from memory forms inside Collection

Tags: c#, mvp

I have a program with several tabPages and inside of each of them an attached form, I want the forms to load dynamically when user clicks on the tabpage, when the user clicks another tabpage I want the form that was in use released form memory and load the new form in memory, I am trying this but I cant get it to work:

```
public void On_SelectedTabChange()
    {
        switch (this._view.TabSeleccionado)
        {
            case "_tabDeposito":
                LoadModule("DepoMainForm");
                break;
            case "_tabProduccion":
                MessageBox.Show("Modulo no implementado");
                break;
        }
    }

    public void LoadModule(string module)
    {
        this._view.OpenForm(module);
    }
```

----------------(View/Form)-------------------

```
public void Attach(IMainCallbacks callback)
    {
        this._tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged +=
            (objSender, e) => callback.On_SelectedTabChange();
    }

    public void OpenForm(string formName)
    {
        switch (formName)
        {
            case "DepoMainForm":
                var forms = Application.OpenForms;
                foreach (var form in forms)//WRONG
                {
                    form.dispose();
                }                  
                DepoMainForm DepoMainForm = new DepoMainForm
                {
                    TopLevel = false,
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    Parent = _tabDeposito,
                    Visible = true,
                    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
                };
                this._tabDeposito.Controls.Add(DepoMainForm);
                var presenter = new DepoMainPresenter(DepoMainForm);
                presenter.Init();                     
                break;
```

The event, in case "DepoMainForm" the form is Instantiated and attached to the tabpage, in the other case the MessageBos shows accordingly, but I dont know how to dispose all forms except for the one that gets loaded when user changes the tab page.

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved with this:

```
 public void OpenForm(string formName)
    {
        switch (formName)
        {
            case "DepoMainForm":
                DisposeForms();
                DepoMainForm DepoMainForm = new DepoMainForm
                {
                    TopLevel = false,
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    Parent = _tabDeposito,
                    Visible = true,
                    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
                };
                this._tabDeposito.Controls.Add(DepoMainForm);
                var presenter = new DepoMainPresenter(DepoMainForm);
                presenter.Init();

                break;

        }

    }

    public void DisposeForms()
    {
        List<Form> toBeDisposed = new List<Form>();
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if(form.Tag != null && form.Tag.ToString() != "MainForm")
            toBeDisposed.Add(form);
        }
        foreach (Form form in toBeDisposed)
        {
            form.Dispose();
        }
    }
```